# 3-D geometry : three vertices of a ||gm ABCD is (3,-1,2), (1,2,-4) & (-1,1,2). Find the coordinate of the fourth vertex.

Tags: geometry, 3d

The question is

> Three vertices of a **parallelogram ABCD** are **A(3,-1,2), B(1,2,-4)** and **C(-1,1,2)**. Find the coordinate of the fourth vertex.

To get the answer I tried the distance formula, equated AB=CD and AC=BD.

Comment: Doesn't this have more than one solution, depending on the order of the vertices in the parallelogram or is D meant to be connected to A and C?

Comment: A upper left, B upper right, C lower right, D lower left.

Comment: $AC$ and $BD$ must have the same mid point. The mid point of $AC$ is $(1,0,2)$ and hence $D$ is $(1, -2, 8)$

Answer (score 7):

If you have a parallelogram ABCD, then you know the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{DC}$ need to be equal as they are parallel and have the same length. Since we know that $\vec{AB}=(-2,\,3,-6)$ you can easily calculate $D$ since you (now) know $C$ and $\vec{CD}(=-\vec{AB})$. We get for $\vec{0D}=\vec{0C}+\vec{CD}=(-1,\,1,\,2)+(\,2,-3,\,6)=(\,1,-2,\,8)$ and hence $D(\,1,-2,\,8)$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to consider distance. You need to compute the difference vectors between adjacent sides. For instance, compute the difference vector from $B$ to $A$ and then add that to $C$.

Answer (score 1):

use mid point formulae
let point be $d(a,b,c)$
so,
     $$\frac{(a+1)}2 = \frac{(3-1)}2$$
so $a=1$
similarly find c ad b as well